# JSF-Login-Page in HTTP-Response despite valid JSESSIONID

Tags: jsf, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, jaas

I think this a HTTP-related problem.

I want to use my (JAX-RS) RESTeasy Service on a (JEE6) JBoss AS 7 Server from an Android Device. The *RESTeasy* Service is working fine. I am using on the Client-Side the *Restlet-Client*. This works too - *without* Security.

I want to use my JAAS-Formbased Security for the Pattern `/rest/*` in *web.xml*. So I have to send a HTTP-POST-Request with the Form-Data (`j_username` and `j_password`) to `/foo/j_security_check`.

I get the `JSESSIONID` from the first Response by the Server:

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=uKUqlkUWdhX2l-FihiWyeSJr.undefined; Path=/foo
  Pragma: No-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
  X-Powered-By: JSF/2.0
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 1028
  Date: Wed, 15 Aug 2012 11:42:59 GMT
```

For this anonymous session I am authenticating ...

**Header:**

```
  POST /foo/j_security_check HTTP/1.1
  Date: Wed, 15 Aug 2012 11:42:58 GMT
  Accept: text/html
  Host: 172.24.47.5:8080
  User-Agent: Restlet-Framework/2.0.14
  Cookie: JSESSIONID=uKUqlkUWdhX2l-FihiWyeSJr.undefined
  Content-Length: 62
  Content-Language: *
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
```

**Content:**

```
j_username=Bob&j_password=a
```

... and it works: **JBoss-Security-TRACE**:

> 2012-08-15 13:22:26,829 TRACE
>   [org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule]
>   (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8080-4) **User 'Bob' authenticated, loginOk=true**

**Now the Problem:** In the following request I want to GET the REST-URL (using the Cookie JSESSIONID):

```
  GET /foo/rest/sync/products HTTP/1.1
  Date: Wed, 15 Aug 2012 11:42:59 GMT
  Accept: application/json
  Host: 172.24.47.5:8080
  User-Agent: Restlet-Framework/2.0.14
  Cookie: JSESSIONID=uKUqlkUWdhX2l-FihiWyeSJr.undefined
  Content-Length: 0
```

But instead of returning the Response with JSON Content, the server is returning the JSF-Login-Page, because it want's me to authenticate again(?):

```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Pragma: No-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 01:00:00 CET
  X-Powered-By: JSF/2.0
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 936
  Date: Wed, 15 Aug 2012 11:42:59 GMT

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> ... ... ... </html>
```

If I login with the Browser and then open the REST-URL it works fine. This is the GET-Request by the Browser:

```
  GET http://localhost:8080/foo/rest/sync/products HTTP/1.1
  Host: localhost:8080
  Connection: keep-alive
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko)    
  Chrome/19.0.1084.56 Safari/536.5
  Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
  Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
  Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
  Cookie: JSESSIONID=royq26yLd7REOz2otiZdTl6j.undefined
```

Anyone has an idea? I think the problem lays in the last request (GET /foo/rest/sync/products), because in the Browser it works fine.

Thanks

Comment: If I steal the JSESSIONID from the Browser it works, too.

Comment: Can you please post your `web.xml` file?  I strongly suspect that the FacesServlet may be mapped to * or the Security servlet filter is probably intercepting the REST web service requests and forwarding you to the login page.

Comment: I am now at home and can't post the web.xml until tomorrow. The RESTeasy Servlet is mapped to "/rest/*" (because I set the property to start every REST-URI with "/rest"). The JSF-Servlet is mapped to "*.xhtml". I got it working by this strange "workaround": **1.** GET the JSESSIONID **2.** GET the REST-URI (and be denied) **3.** Use the JSESSIONID   and authenticate **4.** GET the REST-URI **again** (Step 2 is new). Then it works, which is really strange. I don't know why the Login behaves like this. But if I open the Browser the steps are similar, because I get denied first and THEN login.